# How to access uid using Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I wanted to access the uid of a user using javascript on the node environment and creating another reference to the accessed value "name" . My code and firebase data structure is as follows

```
exports.getData = functions.database.ref('/Followers/{uid}/{uid}/name')
    .onWrite(event => {

      //Getting the name data value

      const name = event.data.val();

      return admin.database().ref('/Accessed Name').set(name);
    });
```

My Firebase sample data structure:

[image: 1]

The accessed data "name" should create a reference such as the example below.

[image: The accessed data "name"]

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do here.  Are you just trying to get the value of the matched uid in the wildcards in your database trigger path?

Comment: Yes, i wanted to access the two uids

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get the wildcard values from the matched path, you can use the event parameters:

```
exports.getData = functions.database.ref('/Followers/{uid1}/{uid2}/name')
    .onWrite(event => {

    const uid1 = event.params.uid1
    const uid2 = event.params.uid2

}
```

Note that you have to give them different names in the path to get different values.  In your example, you gave them the same name.

See [the documentation for database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

#### Cloud functions V1.0

To be able to get the `uid` in the version 1.0, you need to do the following:

```
exports.getData = functions.database.ref('/Followers/{uid1}/{uid2}/name')
.onWrite((change, context) => {

 const uid1 = context.params.uid1
 const uid2 = context.params.uid2

});
```

The `data` parameter represents the data that triggered the function.

The `context` parameter provides information about the function's execution.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: Not quite working for me still... "TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid1' of undefined". I tried both context.params.uid1 and change.params.uid1. Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647170/firebase-functions-cannot-read-property-user-id-of-undefined, also params can only be accessed using "context" @user2091936

Comment: Perfect! Solved my problem. Seem that I was just pushing the function but not updating the headers that also had the changes for the new API. All working now. Thanks!