# Firebase functions: cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to do a simple hello world firebase function with my mobile app, I want to log the user ID so I can see that the function does work.
This is my current javascript code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}').onWrite((event) => {

  console.log('Testing stuff', event.params.user_id);

  return;
});
```

It does trigger when new data is written to specific databasetable but this error shows up:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:8:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:700:26
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

The notification database looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Note to everyone who landed here: It's likely that you're using an old version of some tutorial that hasn't been updated to use the API for the Cloud Functions for Firebase API version 1.0.  Please notify the creators of the tutorial that their content is out of date.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**You need to install the latest firebase-functions and firebase-admin:**

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

to be able to use the new API, check here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set_up_and_initialize

**Change this:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}').onWrite((event) => {

console.log('Testing stuff', event.params.user_id);
```

**into this:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {

console.log('Testing stuff', context.params.user_id);
```

> For `onWrite` and `onUpdate` events, the data parameter has `before` and `after` fields. Each of these is a `DataSnapshot` with the same methods available in [admin.database.DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot)

---

> `params`
>
> An object containing the values of the wildcards in the path parameter provided to the ref() method for a Realtime Database trigger.

more info here:

[Cloud functions v1.0 Changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff)

[EventContext#params](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#params)

[Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change)