# Need an assistance with Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a cloud function using node.js and I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
>       at exports.FindRoom.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:299:39)
>       at Object. (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)

From this function:

```
exports.FindRoom = functions.database.ref(`/FindRoom/{user_id}`).onWrite((event) =>{
        var user_id = event.params.user_id;
        console.log("user_id",user_id);
        var user_question = event.data.val();
        console.log("user_question",user_question);
        if (!event.data.val()) {
          return console.log('A game room was deleted from database',user_id);
        }
```

It's a first time I'm using Firebase and Cloud Functions, and the function worked well before I made npm update for Firebase. After update I'm getting this error and could not find a solution.

Comment: I believe this question was already asked?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647170/firebase-functions-cannot-read-property-user-id-of-undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but Firebase just got updated to its v1 and it changes stuff about database. I received an email this morning.
You can see the changes [over here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?utm_source=email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=cloud_functions_v1.0).

Hope it helps!

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexL I'm glaed it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The path string needs to be a literal string, not a template. So replace the backticks (`` ` ``) with regular (single or double) quotes:

```
exports.FindRoom = functions.database.ref("/FindRoom/{user_id}").onWrite(...
```