# Firestore TypeError: Cannot read property 'userID' of undefined

Tags: android, node.js, firebase

I'm trying to test a very simple nodeJS function that monitors if a new document added to a collection (Notifications) then assign the super document id (`userID`) of that document and the child document id (`notificationID`) and print them to the console.

```
'use-strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Notifications/{notificationID}').onWrite(event => {

    const to_user = event.params.userID;
    const notification_id = event.params.notificationID;

    console.log("Notification ID: " + notification_id + " Sent to: " + to_user );

});
```

And this is the output at Firebase Functions:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userID' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.firestore.document.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:8:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:700:26
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: What version of firebase-functions are you using?  If 1.0, are you aware that the APIs have changed?

Comment: Beta version. No, I'm not. It's my first time to use firebase-functions

Comment: If you started using Cloud Functions today, and you create a new project with the latest version of the Firebase CLI, then you're using 1.0.  In 1.0, there is no more event.params.

Comment: Yes, I've just started today. But, there's a word (BETA) next to Functions, so I'm not sure what version it is. Any suggestions how to assign the value to the variable? (the replacement of event.params)?

Comment: Cloud Functions infrastructure is in beta.  The Firebase SDKs are fully released.  What does your package.json say about firebase-functions?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.0"
  }

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647170/firebase-functions-cannot-read-property-user-id-of-undefined

Answer (score 0):

You're using the new 1.0 SDK, but writing code for the old versions.  The first parameter to the callback passed to [onWrite()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onWrite) is now a [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) object.  The second parameter (which you're not using here) is now an [EventContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext) object that has a [params](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#params) property which has the userID wildcard value you're looking for.