# Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to send device to device push notification through firebase cloud functions. I am writing node.js script

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{user_id}/{rec_user_id}').onWrite((event) => {

const sender_user_id = event.params.user_id;
const receiver_user_id = event.params.rec_user_id;

console.log('We have a notification from : '+ sender_user_id+  " | Receiced by " + receiver_user_id);

return;

});
```

After deploying function on firebase cloud i got an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
```

Full error log is :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:28:40)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:700:26
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

I got an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647170/firebase-functions-cannot-read-property-user-id-of-undefined)

It was working fine, but when i used

```
if(!event.data.val()){

return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', sender_user_id);

}
```

Firebase log again start to give me an error message saying

```
Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
```

How to get rid of these errors ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase functions: cannot read property 'user\_id' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647170/firebase-functions-cannot-read-property-user-id-of-undefined)

Comment: I am getting error cannot read property 'val', how to solve this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding `val()` you need to do the following:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{user_id}/{rec_user_id}').onWrite((change,context) => {

const afterData=change.after.val();
});
```

Since you are using `onWrite()` then the data parameter should be `change`, which has the `before` and `after` properties, each of these is a `DataSnapshot` that has the following methods:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot

Also for reference:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change

Comment: But @Peter can you please tell me, why i am getting error when using onWrite() with **event** parameter

Comment: no problem, it is because the cloud function was updated to version 1.0, so there is not event parameter anymore. Here read this:https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff. It has been released like last week so I'm gonna guess that most of the online tutorials are outdated

Comment: I want more help, i want to implement push notification i=on 2 differect event ( i.e. 1. When someone send me a message nd 2) when anyone commented on my post .. How to achieve this ?

Comment: please ask it in another question with more details about what you are trying to do