# Firebase Functions - ReferenceError: event is not defined

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to do a simple notification function 
but every time i fire the function i get ERROR

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
>       at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:23:32)
>       at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:758:24
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Or i get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined

I got an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708163/cannot-read-property-user-id-of-undefined?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but i't didn't help at all , and i can't find the problem . this is my code

```
'use strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change,context) => {

const user_id = event.params.user_id;
const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

console.log('We have a notification from : ', user_id);

if(!context.data.val()){

return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', 
notification_id);

}

const fromUser =admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

console.log('You have new notification from  : ', from_user_id);

const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`Users/${from_user_id}/name`).once('value');
const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

return Promise.all([userQuery, deviceToken]).then(result => {

  const userName = result[0].val();
  const token_id = result[1].val();

  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title : "New Friend Request",
      body: `${userName} has sent you request`,
      icon: "default",
      click_action : "none"
    },
    data : {
      from_user_id : from_user_id
    }
  };

  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

    return console.log('This was the notification Feature');

     });

   });

  });

});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746905/firebase-typeerror-cannot-read-property-val-of-undefined/49746976#49746976

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647170/firebase-functions-cannot-read-property-user-id-of-undefined/49647257#49647257

Answer (score 3):

You never defined `event`, so it's undefined.  You're trying to access a property on an undefined variable.  Did you mean `context.params.user_id`?

(You're probably using an out of date tutorial. I see bad "sendNotification" functions like this all the time on Stack Overflow. Let the author know.)

Comment: where should i defined it , i read about the event , it can't be used now

Comment: That's why I suggested you use `context` instead.

Comment: how should i use it , can you write a code of how to use it ?

Comment: you see here `onWrite((change, context)` i'm not using the event at all 
and i defined the user id as `const user_id = context.params.user_id;`