# firebase backend function cannot read property

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

hello everyone i am kind of new to android programming and almost have no idea in js coding , i followed a tutorial to create a firebase function and when i did it it seem to have an error , my question may be stupid but i need help , i am getting an error on the second line from the user_id ( i put a ``` just for Illustration :

````
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/n/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {
const user_id = event.params.```user_id```;
const notification_id = event.params.```notification_id```;
````

this is my database :

```
 -n

--ti9MmffcXLT38uagj5J3fTqshjf1

----LBlr1He51ln-yTyQOdM

--------f: "FjVudM9BBahhCd0eta9lWS8tUoY2"

--------t : 5
```

i am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:28:31)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:710:26
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

my hands are tied here and i really need to finish this , any help will be appricated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase functions: cannot read property 'user\_id' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647170/firebase-functions-cannot-read-property-user-id-of-undefined)

Comment: The tutorial you followed must be kind of old.  The API for Cloud Functions for Firebase has changed.  The changes have been documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff).  Consider starting over and learning the new API.

Comment: almost but the slice difference here is i am saving the value as const @PeterHaddad

Comment: that does not matter

Comment: @PeterHaddad you are right but i am getting another error that there is no event :W 

` ReferenceError: event is not defined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:39:7) `

Comment: here is a piece of my code :
` exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/n/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((data, context) => {
  const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/n/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');
  return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {
 `

Comment: @sleemannabwani `onWrite((change,context)`