# TypeError in firebase function while sending notification

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Code

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref(`/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}/`).onWrite(event =>{
const user_id = event.params.user_id;
const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

console.log('We have a notification to send to ', user_id);

if(!event.data.val()){
return console.log("A Notification has been deleted from the database", notification_id);
}


const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/UserData/${user_id}/TokenID`).once('value');
return deviceToken.then(result =>{

const token_id = result.val();

const payload ={
notification: {
title: "Friend request",
body: "You have recieved a new Friend Request",
icon: "default"
}
};

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>{
return console.log('This was the notofication Feature');
});

});

});
```

Error

[image]

It just sucks that all code for an app can be done in android using java but the functions should be in javascript... New to the language so not sure what the error even means... Can someone help me solve it please?

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref(`/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}/`).onWrite(event =>{
const user_id = event.params.user_id;
const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

console.log('We have a notification to send to ', user_id);

if(!event.data.val()){
  return console.log("A Notification has been deleted from the database", notification_id);
}
```

into this:

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref(`/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}/`).onWrite((change,context) =>{
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

console.log('We have a notification to send to ', user_id);

if(!change.after.val()){
return console.log("A Notification has been deleted from the database", notification_id);
}
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: Error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:10:29)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:109:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:139:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:730:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647170/firebase-functions-cannot-read-property-user-id-of-undefined